# Sencha Touch App crashes on Windows Phone 8

Tags: html, extjs, console, windows-phone-8

I have developed an app for iOs and Android with Sencha Touch. Now i want bring these app to Windows Phone 8.

I migrated the framework to 2.2 and all works fine. In the internet explorer 10 on Windows 8 the app works great. But when i try to open the app on the windows phone with the browser, the app crashes alway on the same action.

I used a card layout and destroy the last view manually, because i made better experiences with this procedure.

I'm reale desperate, because i don't know where i can fix it. Unfortunately, there is no developer console like in chrome. From my manully bugfixing i know that the javascript code works till the and of the called function.

I also try the app as build with PhoneGap and there are the same problems.

Does any body know, if there are some problems with a Ext.Js container in card layout and windows phone 8?

And additional, does any body know a good way to check HTML/CSS/Javascript Code on the Windows Phone 8? Maybe on the same way like on the iPad.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to successfully deploy an sencha touch application on windows phone 8 following the steps in the following link:

[Deploy Sencha touch app on Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844818/deploy-sencha-touch-app-on-windows-phone)

I added the plugins I needed using the following command after installing Git and set it to be available from the command prompt of windows:

```
cordova plugin add <URL_GIT_REPO>
```

Instead of using the package files, I used the command:

```
sencha app build native
```

and I used the **app.js** and **app.json** files generated that were created in the path *SenchaTouchAppFolder/build/native/AppName*

also did the following: I had to get a developer account, and checked the device after installing **visual studio 2012 express** and **windows phone SDK 8**.

When deploying the application on the **device** in **Debug** mode, you can view exception messages in the output window of Visual Studio.

First make sure that the project includes the **app.json** file. For example to build the solution in the output window should display the following message:

```
1> Adding www\app.json
```

In the **csproj** file should include the following elements:

```
<Content Include = "www\app.json" /> 
<Content Include = "www\resources\sample\data.json" />
```

I also modified the following lines of code to add support for JSON responses needed in the model from my local storage in **cordovalib/XHRHelper.cs** file.

```
 var funk = function () {
                        window.__onXHRLocalCallback = function (responseCode, responseText) {
                            alias.status = responseCode;
                            if (responseCode == '200') {
                                alias.responseText = responseText;
                                try {
                                    JSON.parse(responseText);
                                } catch (e) {
                                    Object.defineProperty(alias, 'responseXML', {
                                        get: function () {
                                            return new DOMParser().parseFromString(this.responseText, 'text/xml');
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                Object.defineProperty(alias, 'responseJSON', {
                                    get: function () {
                                        return new DOMParser().parseFromString(this.responseText, 'text/json');
                                    }
                                });

                            }else {
                                alias.onerror && alias.onerror(responseCode);
                            }
```

A useful tool to debug css errors is the emulation tool internet explorer 11

```
F12 > Emulation > Explorer Profile > Windows Phone
```

This tool can also be useful: [Remote HTML5 debugging on Windows Phone with weinre](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/06/12/remote-html5-debugging-on-windows-phone-with-weinre/)