# Deploy Sencha touch app on Windows Phone

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, windows-phone

I have an existing Sencha touch project which I would like to deploy on a Windows Phone device. So far I have tried to combine Sencha touch with Phonegap to deploy it via Phonegap, but I did not succeed in doing so.

Since Sencha touch 2.2 Windows Phone support is builtin, according to [this post](http://www.sencha.com/blog/hello-sencha-touch-2-2/).

Can someone point me on howto deploy an existing Sencha touch project to Windows Phone using Sencha touch 2.2 with Sencha CMD. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: For further clarification: By deploying I mean packaging as it is described in the official documentation (there it says that only Android and iOS are currently supported): http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/native_packaging

EDIT2: If packaging with Sencha touch is simply not possible as of now, I will be glad to hear about a solution using Phonegap (or something else) to package/deploy an existing Sencha touch app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to package a Windows Phone 8 app.
Using sencha cmd 3.1.2 and cordova 3.0.9 I did the following:

1. Build a package from existing App using Sencha touch (execute the following in *SenchaTouchAppFolder*):

   ```
   sencha app build package
   ```
2. Create new empty Cordova project (execute where your cordova project folder should be placed):

   ```
   cordova create ProjectName
   ```
3. Add desired platforms (execute in newly created folder [*CordovaProjectFolder*]):

   ```
   cordova platform add wp8
   ```
4. Remove all content in *CordovaProjectFolder*/www except config.xml
5. Edit config.xml to reflect project settings
6. Copy/Move content from *SenchaTouchAppFolder*/build/*AppName*/package to *CordovaProjectFolder*/www
7. Edit index.html add line to include cordova.js in head-Section

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
   ```
8. Execute 'cordova build' in *CordovaProjectFolder*

-> The generated files should be in '*CordovaProjectFolder*/platforms/wp8'

Comment: Appreciate your effort and posting your solution. It works for me in a single hit.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to package a Windows Phone 8 app using sencha cmd 5.0.0 and cordova 3.5.0 I did the following:

Perform an upgrade to the sencha application (execute the following in SenchaTouchAppFolder):

```
sencha app upgrade
```

If the following error message appear

```
[ERR] org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: SyntaxError: illegal character (C:\Sench
a\Sencha\Cmd\5.0.0.160\ant\ant-util.js#605(eval)#1)
```

Just edit the app.json file and remove  invalid characters at beginning of file, then build a package from existing App (run the following command in SenchaTouchAppFolder):

```
sencha app build native
```

After creating the cordova project and add the respective platform, if you're using cordova plugins you can install them by, after installing git (execute in newly created folder [CordovaProjectFolder]):

```
cordova plugin add <URL_GIT_REPO>
```

Copy/Move content from SenchaTouchAppFolder/build/native/AppName to 'CordovaProjectFolder/platforms/wp8/www'

Finally edit index.html add line to include cordova.js in head-Section.