# Sencha Touch 2.2/2.3 not working on Windows Phone 8 / IE10

Tags: windows-phone-8, sencha-touch-2

I want to create a sencha touch demo to work on Windows Phone 8 (Lumia 925). But it's not working and I tried with Sencha Touch 2.2 and 2.3.

To reproduce my problem, I have JUST create my first app with the official guide http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/guide/getting_started (just the cmd sencha generate app MyApp ../MyApp) and do nothing else.

After that, I tried this app on chrome on my computer, it's okay. But it's not working with IE10 and WP8 (Lumia 925). The symptoms are a a blue screen with a small white square in the center.

IE10 said errors are :

SCRIPT438: L’objet ne gère pas la propriété ou la méthode « defineGetter » sencha-touch-all.js, Ligne 3071 Caractère 13 SCRIPT438: L’objet ne gère pas la propriété ou la méthode « get » sencha-touch-all.js, Ligne 9001 Caractère 13

But the problem comes from the sencha-touch library...

Should I do something else to make it work on WP8 and IE10 than just the basis template ? Compil, how, config ?

You can have my files here : http://sendbox.fr/pro/uzn729c9oknz/Sencha23.zip.html

Problem : http:// i.stack.imgur.com/yJzXa.png (just remove the space after http:// to see the picture !).

Comment: Embed your code and image in the question - don't make people traverse somewhere else to see your files (and then have to dig through code) - just post the relevant code. And don't make people deal with removing spaces in a url - embed the image properly - there's a button on the editor.

Answer (score 0):

If you have got the same problem, you have to force the document mode for IE with this in your index.html page :

Answer (score 0):

I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16235840/sencha-touch-app-crashes-on-windows-phone-8), first a useful tool to fix this error is the emulation tool internet explorer 11

```
F12 > Emulation > Explorer Profile > Windows Phone
```