# How to package Simple Sencha MVC app for Window Phone 8

Tags: extjs, windows-phone-8

I am able to wrap sencha APP in window Phone 8 if using UIView Control or PhonegapView and accessing app over localhost.

But not able to package app when putting all pages in www folder (Tried with phonegap also).
Other Non Sencha web APP works fine.

I have searched on forum . Many people are facing same issue.
Can any one post a successful solution?

I am using latest Sencha touch 2.3.1

I am getting that first sencha need to be packaged and then it could be put in www folder.
But i am not able to get the correct packaging required which can work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16235840/sencha-touch-app-crashes-on-windows-phone-8/); instead of using the package files, I used the command:

```
sencha app build native
```

and I used the **app.js** and **app.json** files generated that were created in the path

```
build/native/<YOUR_APP>
```