# Sencha + Windows phone 8 : Launch function is not invoked

Tags: extjs, cordova, windows-phone-8

I have built a sencha application using Sencha cmd.

I have integrated it to windows phone using cordova.

Now, when launching the app, after splash screen, a white screen comes and stays for ever.

I trying putting an alert in the launch function (in app.js where view is created) and found out that the launch function does not fire.

What could be the reason of this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the issue that I was facing. The sencha app is using a store with SQL proxy. But since SQL proxy is not supported on Windows phone (but supported on other platforms viz. iOS, Android), so the launch function was not getting called.

Answer (score 0):

I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16235840/sencha-touch-app-crashes-on-windows-phone-8/) with a JSON proxy and I had to modify the following lines of code in **cordovalib/XHRHelper.cs** file.

```
 var funk = function () {
                        window.__onXHRLocalCallback = function (responseCode, responseText) {
                            alias.status = responseCode;
                            if (responseCode == '200') {
                                alias.responseText = responseText;
                                try {
                                    JSON.parse(responseText);
                                } catch (e) {
                                    Object.defineProperty(alias, 'responseXML', {
                                        get: function () {
                                            return new DOMParser().parseFromString(this.responseText, 'text/xml');
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                Object.defineProperty(alias, 'responseJSON', {
                                    get: function () {
                                        return new DOMParser().parseFromString(this.responseText, 'text/json');
                                    }
                                });

                            }else {
                                alias.onerror && alias.onerror(responseCode);
                            }
```